# Webpack encoding issue plus webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've been using the same webpack build system for about a year, and now I am consistently getting the following errors, every 2-3 browser refreshes. I've never upgraded node, npm, or anything in my `package.json` on the server this build runs. The current build system will not succeed if there are any JS syntax errors.

**Errors:**

- Invalid or unexpected token (bundle-1.js)
- webpackJsonp is not defined (bundle-2.js)

When I inspect `bundle-1.js`, I see the following encoding issue, even after I set the `EncodingPlugin` to encode UTF-8:

[image]

I've read other SO posts about "webpackJsonp is not defined" and tried:

- Loading my dependencies in the different orders
- setting `minChuncks` for `CommonsChunkPlugin` to Infinity

I am using the following software versions:

- node v4.6.2
- npm v3.9.0
- webpack 1.10.1
- grunt webpack 1.0.11
- webpack encoding plugin 0.2.1

Any help for why these errors are appearing at run time is appreciated.

Comment: have you defined it with the `require` statement in your main js file?

Comment: yes, the build is successful, the errors are only shown at run time in the browser

Comment: another issue might be the way you are referencing your JS script files. What are you using for templates?

Comment: we're using dust but the script tags in the template are vanilla html

Comment: https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter/issues/88 - same issue, try to change your JS files.

Comment: I actually tried that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination has solved my issue:

- Upgrading webpack to `1.12.9`
- Adding the Encoding Plugin, as well as setting the `minChunks` parameter to `"Infinity"` in the `CommonsChunkPlugin` constructor

  ```
    new EncodingPlugin({
      encoding: 'UTF-8'
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin('shared', '<filename>.js', null, Infinity),
  ```

Furthermore, the S3 bucket which was serving the bundled js was missing a `content-type` header as well as a `content-encoding` header. `content-encoding` was most important since the content was compressed with `gzip`. Moving to a new bucket helped solved this.